# Positioning Items in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` bound to data like this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="MainPanel" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Definition}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In my data model I have a `y` coordinate for each item, to position the item vertically on the screen and each item is of variable height (because of `TextWrapping`).

I need each item to be positioned on the `y` coordinate unless it overlaps with the previous item, in which case it is placed below the previous item.

I thought to use the `Margin` property to do this but it is actually not that straight forward...

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: i think you need to write your own wrap panel for this.

Comment: My WPF is rusty but I'd say: replace the ItemsControl panel with a canvas (`<ItemsPanelTemplate><Canvas /></ItemsPanelTemplate>`), then bind your items to the `Canvas.Top` dependency property (`<TextBlock Text="..." Canvas.Top="{Binding y}" ...`)

Comment: Oh, I missed the "don't overlap" requirement. My solution won't work then

Comment: I'd try this with a custom StackPanel and an attached property like `MyCustomStackPanel.MinY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think change `TextBlock.Margin.Top` is a easy way to do this.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="your model collection"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Need ItemsControl for calculation. -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}">
                    <TextBlock.Margin>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource calcOffsetY}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Margin>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And the converter.

```
public class CalcOffsetY : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var tbk = (TextBlock)values[0];
        var offsetY = tbk.TranslatePoint(tbk.RenderTransformOrigin, (UIElement)tbk.Tag).Y -
            tbk.Margin.Top;
        var y = ((YourModelType)tbk.DataContext).Y;

        tbk.SetCurrentValue(TextBlock.MarginProperty, new Thickness(tbk.Margin.Left, y > offsetY ? y - offsetY : 0,
            tbk.Margin.Right, tbk.Margin.Bottom));
        tbk.UpdateLayout(); // Update layout immediately, so next item will get correct result.

        return Binding.DoNothing; // Already nothing to do.
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising - I'll let you know how i get on... Thank you for your help. I don't understand why you have added: `<Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>`... Why is that?

Comment: Also, will this automatically move my items when `Y` changes?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia The `ActualWidth` binding will cause recalculation every time when width of  `ItemsControl` changed including the first time while doing Initialization. And if you want this respone to change of  `Y`, you need to add one more `Binding` to `MultiBinding`.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't seem quite right (items *overlap* and positioning is not quite right ie. when `Y = 0` the item is not at the top  ) - https://www.screencast.com/t/IwIdLxobO

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Since you didn't mention the items order, I just simply assumed that they was sorted by Y. Actually, my answer was taken the advantage of WPF's layout calculation to solve the overlap problem. So I recommend that you use a `CollectionViewSource` to instead the collection as binding source, and add a `SortDescription` to `CollectionViewSource`, make the view sort by `Y` automatically.

Comment: Even if i sort the items by `Y` they still overlap ie `this.Add(new tmpModelEntry() { Text = "item 4", Y = 0 });  this.Add(new tmpModelEntry() { Text = "item 5", Y = 60 }); this.Add(new tmpModelEntry() { Text = "item 6", Y = 63 });       this.Add(new tmpModelEntry() { Text = "item 7", Y = 70 });` - see here: https://www.screencast.com/t/f00qlFCoKxp

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Yes, you are right. I had only done some basic tests before posted it. I just forgot `RenderTransform` will not effect layout. So, this is a dead end. I will leave it for a day then delete it. Sorry for wasted your time. I will still try to find a solid one to solve this problem.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Instead of `RenderTransform`, I used `Margin` this time as you mention in the question. The result seem fine. Answer was updated.

Comment: You truly rock! Thank you.